# Scraping webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to write a Python script to scrape data from this [webpage.](https://robot-reviewer.vortext.systems/#report/ZhXMMAPouI9IfERppg33G) I am trying to scrape the data from the second table `('class': 'char-pico-table')` and am using this script to do so:

```
def getPICO(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    print (r.content)
```

However, this prints this:

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html class="view">\n  <head>\n    <title>RobotReviewer: Automating evidence synthesis</title>\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">\n    <meta name="google" content="notranslate">\n\n    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">\n    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css">\n    <link rel="stylesheet alternative prefetch" type=text/css href="/css/report.css">\n\n    <!-- Preload examples -->\n    <link rel="prefetch" href="/report_view/Tvg0-pHV2QBsYpJxE2KW-/html">\n    <link rel="prefetch" href="/report_view/_fzGUEvWAeRsqYSmNQbBq/html">\n    <link rel="prefetch" href="/report_view/HBkzX1I3Uz_kZEQYeqXJf/html">\n\n    <!-- / Preload examples -->\n\n\n    <script src="/scripts/modernizr.js"></script>\n    <script src="/scripts/spa/scripts/vendor/pdfjs/pdf.js"></script>\n    <script src="/scripts/spa/scripts/vendor/compatibility.js"></script>\n    <script data-main="/scripts/main" src="/scripts/require.js"></script>\n\n    <script>\n     PDFJS.disableWebGL = false;\n     CSRF_TOKEN = "1508009356##6a03b1bf519972b27a0d871ae4823eb3a3366c0c";\n    </script>\n  </head>\n\n  <body>\n    <nav id="top-bar" class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">\n      <div>\n        <ul class="title-area">\n          <li class="name">\n            <h1><a href="/"><img src="/img/logo.svg" width="190px"></a></h1>\n          </li>\n        </ul>\n\n        <section class="top-bar-section">\n          <ul class="right">\n            <li><a href="http://www.robotreviewer.net">About</a></li>\n          </ul>\n        </section>\n      </div>\n    </nav>\n\n    <div id="breadcrumbs"></div>\n\n    <main id="main"></main>\n\n\n  </body>\n</html>'
```

which is not the output that I see when I view the page in my browser - it contains none of the data that I wish to scrape. Why is this not the case?

When viewing the page in a web browser it looks like this:

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Elprt.png)

Comment: What did you expect to get instead?

Comment: Yes, what you want as output?

Comment: The website loads data using javascript, you need to use python library `selenium` to extract data

Comment: The content appears to be in an iframe, you need to crawl the iframe content.

Comment: @Sarcoma , to crawl the iframe also, you will need to use somthing like selenium, cant be done with requests

Comment: @Stack Is it not possible to access the iframe content at it's src url?

Comment: @Sarcoma, checked there is no source url for the frame, may be some background script loads it

Comment: If the data from that webpage is what you are after then you should follow this link. https://robot-reviewer.vortext.systems/report_view/ZhXMMAPouI9IfERppg33G/html you will find it easy to parse data from here with usual requests.

Comment: Why this question got downvoted? I suppose who did this has got the ability to provide any effective answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment from [@Shahin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7769242/shahin), I wrote the following code, which gave me the data in a JSON format from which I was easily able to extract the data.

```
result = json.loads(requests.get('https://robot-reviewer.vortext.systems/report_view/'+id+'/json').content)
```